# DROP ROLE IF EXISTS fails with an "does not exist" error, instead of a NOTICE

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-12

A set of 20 month old new DB provisioning .sql files suddenly stopped working on our PostGRES 12.7 instance hosted on the IBM Cloud.  Every `DROP ROLE IF EXISTS` clause now fails with an ERROR, where previously it would give notice and continue with configuration, even if run on a new, empty database.

The exact commands:

```
DROP ROLE IF EXISTS "anonymous";
```

or

```
DROP ROLE IF EXISTS "FLUMMOXED";
```

return

```
 ERROR:  role "FLUMMOXED" does not exist
 SQL state: 42704
```

instead of a NOTICE.

What I've tried:

- I've been through the PostGRES manual, and this command hasn't changed since PostGRES 8.
- I've read through the other posts, which emphasize sensitivity to casing.
- I've checked the 12.8 upgrade log, and this command isn't mentioned.
- I've tried the command on an empty, new DB, and it fails there as well.

Has anyone seen this before?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not seeing it here on my source built instance: `select version(); PostgreSQL 12.7... , DROP ROLE IF EXISTS "FLUMMOXED"; NOTICE:  role "FLUMMOXED" does not exist, skipping`. This must be an IBM Cloud thing.

Comment: I agree with Adrian, I suggest contacting IBM Cloud support.

Comment: Was the "empty, new DB" on the same instance as the other one, or on a different instance still on IBM cloud, or somewhere else?  Is this an IBM-managed database, or just regular database software you installed onto IBM-managed hardware?

Comment: @jjanes It's an empty, new DB on a new empty instance of IBM Cloud SaaS postgres-as-a-service.

Comment: This is question for IBM support.